# How to bake normals using modifiers only?

Tags: modifiers, normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have an UV-unwrapped base mesh that I want to bake tangent normals into. Only detail I need is a few bevel modifiers and a subdivision surface. How can I bake the smooth version without using cage objects etc?

Comment: While not exactly answer to the question, it might be easier to duplicate the object with modifiers, apply them for the duplicate and use it as highpoly, remove modifiers for the other one and bake normals in tnagent space to it like to the lowpoly (creating backup copy is also good step)

Comment: I did try doing that, but the normals look weird in some places, and sometimes bleed where they shouldn't. This might work in certain cases though.

Comment: I'm hoping to get some attention to this question. Anyone?

Comment: Easiest way to attract some attention to a question is to [edit] it and provide more details. Show screenshots of how you tried to bake, settings you used etc. For now I can't tell what does it mean "normals look weird in some places" and "sometimes bleed"

Answer (score -1):

You can bake world normals instead of tangent ones

Comment: please, try to add some more info, an example, an image, to make this answer look less like a comment...

Comment: -1. Not enough details. You can expand your answer by adding instructions on how to set this parameter, as well as an explanation of the difference between tangent and world normals.